# Attribute table in QGIS showing a subset of desired features after query builder

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, definition-query

I'm working with some OSM data in QGIS and I want to show only those points that are schools. So I go into query builder and enter "other_tags" LIKE '%"amenity"=>"school"%'.

[image: Query Builder]

This narrows down my features from 7000+ to only 16, which is exactly what I want.

[image: Post-Query Record Alert]

However, when I go to view the attribute table, I only see 3 records.

[image: Attribute Table]

I can see that there are 16 total features after the query, but 3 remain after some filter that I did not apply. I can't locate the source of this filter and don't know why it's limiting my features. In fact, I can see all the features on the map and they're all within the extent.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the SQL select to select the schools and then change the filter box in the bottom left so it says "Show selected features"? Or just then dump those selected features in to a new layer.

Comment: That's definitely one solution and I'll probably end up doing something like that if I can't figure out why this isn't working. Thanks for that! I'm wondering if someone could pinpoint this specific issue though.

Comment: Without having the file and knowing what you've done exactly it will be hard to tell. I hope you figure it out though.

Answer (score 1):

I updated to QGIS 3.4 and it now works. I searched the [changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog34/) for "query builder" and "filters" but it didn't show anything related to the issue, so I'm not sure why. If you're having issues with this and are using something prior to 3.4, then update.